# Increase size of Ubuntu16.04LTS partition and delete DOS

Tags: partitioning

I have Ubuntu and DOS installed in my laptop. The space for Ubuntu is 100GB so I'm running short of space and want to increase the disk size for ubuntu (i don't care about DOS moreover i want to delete it to free up some space , it came preinstalled on my laptop). I've some important softwares installed in Ubuntu so I don't want to format the disk.

How could I make all of the space available to Ubuntu (1TB HDD)?

My disk partitions:

```
priyanshu@Masquerade:~$ sudo parted -l
[sudo] password for priyanshu: 
Model: ATA WDC WD10JPVX-60J (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  8382MB  8381MB  primary   fat32        boot
 2      8382MB  16.8GB  8381MB  primary   fat32        lba
 3      16.8GB  1000GB  983GB   extended
 5      16.8GB  898GB   881GB   logical
 6      898GB   1000GB  102GB   logical   ext4
```

Comment: Gparted will do it for you.